# Is it possible to get URL path in android ? 

Tags: android, browser

It sounds weird but can I programmatically check the user entered URL in default browser ?

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For reasons of security, only the browser can access the information associated with it.

You can register to receive Intents when the browser visits URLs matching a certain scheme/domain/path/combination of the above, but that will just ask the user whether they want to open the link with the browser or your app.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [WebViewCLient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and overidding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method? it will give you control to the url before loading it.

And also try to read this [sample](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/05/override-url-loading-in-webview-android-tutorial/), hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to read the last visited url:

`manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

`yourActivity`

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Cursor mCur = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            null, null, null, null
            );
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    int index = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE); //ACCESSING THE TITLE of the bookmark
    //For a whole list of columns see [BookmarkColumns][1]
    while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
         //do sth
        mCur.moveToNext();
    }

}
```

}